# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table error on Huawei devices

Tags: android, database, huawei-mobile-services

Please help me with the error below which I get on Huawei devices only. I assume these devices store the database somewhere else... or...?

Error message: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: places (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT pl_web_id FROM places ORDER BY pl_web_id DESC LIMIT 1, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)

Here is my DatabaseHelper class:

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH;

private static String DB_NAME = "GuessThePlace";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
    // Log.e("path", DB_PATH);
}

// ==============================================================================

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();


        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

// ==============================================================================

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

// ==============================================================================

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("database/" + DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

// ==============================================================================

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

// ==============================================================================

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

// ==============================================================================

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

// ==============================================================================

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: BOOK (code 1 SQLITE\_ERROR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325161/caused-by-android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-no-such-table-book-code-1)

Comment: @Reza unfortunately no, I have tried all the tricks written in there, but the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Reported only from HUAWEI Y6 2019 devices running android 9 (api 28).
My solution has been not to call "getReadableDatabase()" before copying the database.

```
private boolean isReadableDatabaseNeeded() {
    final ArrayList<String> models = new ArrayList<>();

    if (Build.MANUFACTURER.equals("HUAWEI") && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        // These models are for HUAWEI Y6 2019 (marketing name)
        // Marketing name list: https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html
        models.add("MRD-LX1");
        models.add("MRD-LX1F");
        models.add("MRD-LX1N");
        models.add("MRD-LX3");

        if (models.contains(Build.MODEL)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {
        if (isReadableDatabaseNeeded()) { 
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close() // I had this too, and still not working
        }

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.